# Modificar atributos del setState

Tags: reactjs

**Tengo el siguiente código ReactJs** 
Tengo las siguiente propiedades en el state

```
state = {
    parametros: {
        id: "",
        valor: "",
        nombre: "",
        descripcion: "",
    },
    editar: false,

    data: [],
}
```

y una función que se ejecuta en varios input con el evento onChange

```
onInputValue = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        parametros:{
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        },

        editar: true,
    })
}
```

Pero cuando hago un submit para enviar los datos actualizados al API me mando con

> nombre: Undefined, 
> valor: Undefined, etc

sobre cada atributo de la propiedad de productos
nose como pueda obviar ese pequeño problema

Comment: notaste que declaraste el valor nombre y despues lo queres llamar como name?, por un lado eso, despues como tenes declarado el evento que llamas desde el boton? le hiciste bind?

Comment: Puedes compartir el código del elemento completo?

Comment: David, modifiqué la respuesta original agregando la función `onFormSubmit` (la que llamas dentro de la etiqueta form->OnSubmit), por si tienes algún problema con la configuración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que los parametros del objeto no se esten modificando en conjunto, se puede usar el operador Elipsis ES6 [Example of spread operator with objects](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-spread-operator/), propagar el objeto a modificar e indicar cual propiedad del objeto se modifica, para cada llamada a `setState`:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        parametros: {
            id: "",
            valor: "",
            nombre: "",
            descripcion: "",
        },
        editar: false,
        data: []
    }
    this.onInputValue = this.onInputValue.bind(this);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    
    onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    const data = [...this.state.data, this.state.parametros];
      this.setState({
        data,
        parametros:{
          id: "",
          valor: "",
          nombre: "",
          descripcion: ""
        },
        editar: false
      });
      
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    
 onInputValue = (e) => {
        //console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            parametros:{
                ... this.state.parametros, [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            },editar: true})
    }
    
    render(){
        console.log(this.state.parametros);
        return(
            <div>ID:
            <input
            id="id"
            name="id"
            value={this.state.parametros.id}
            onChange={this.onInputValue}
            />
            
            Valor:
            <input
            id="valor"
            name="valor"
            value={this.state.parametros.valor}
            onChange={this.onInputValue}
            />
            
            Nombre:
            <input
            id="nombre"
            name="nombre"
            value={this.state.parametros.nombre}
            onChange={this.onInputValue}
            />
            Descripcion:
            <input
            id="descripcion"
            name="descripcion"
            value={this.state.parametros.descripcion}
            onChange={this.onInputValue}
            />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

En la función `onFormSubmit`, se usa nuevamente el operador **elipsis**, para propagar el array `data` (que esta vacío), e insertar un nuevo elemento, el objeto `propiedades`. Luego, se pasa esta copia (enhanced object literals ES6) a la función `setState` y se reinician los valores de los `fields`, que estan siendo controlados por la configuración del objeto `state`.

El operador **elipsis** crea copias del objeto, con esto se siguen las mejores prácticas con respecto a la [inmutabilidad del objeto state](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data).

Espero que el código sea parecido a lo que intentas hacer,
Saludos